# Attribute table for shapefile showing nonsense symbols on my PC

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, data-source

I am working with a shapefile which has several hundred rows and 10 or so columns. Usually, the cells contain data, but at the moment they are just showing nonsense symbols (attached). I have tried using the same shapefile on a colleague's computer, and it worked fine. I have also reinstalled QGIS. What is wrong?

[image: broken attribute table]

Comment: This is an issue with the data source code - most likely your colleague had the correct one set, while you don't (e.g. UTF-8).

Comment: This appears to be a codepage issue. You should be reviewing differences in the environment variables between the two user accounts.

Comment: open the layer properties go to the 'Source' tab and look at the "data source encoding", if different between the two computer just set it right on your computer

Comment: Thanks all for help - the issue was indeed to do with the data source code!